# Why does the Community user have votes cast?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes, community-user

If Community is a background process and not a real person then why does its profile show that it has votes cast, and how does it cast them?

How can it decide which answers to upvote or downvote?

See the massive number of upvotes and downvotes cast in its profile:

[image]

Comment: It uses advanced artifical intelligence. As you can see it's learnt to become very critical.

Comment: well those answers not give the technical explanation.

Comment: Though upvotes are not officially explained, most likely they belong to deleted users.

Comment: @iPhoneDev technical reason is to preserve history of the votes. Deleted posts still got a score visible to 10k users and mods so the score needs some record somewhere.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thanks for explain.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Mind putting that answer in an answer?

Comment: Perhaps it's better to appropriately update the duplicates @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @Bart but dupes don't really ask for the reason so it feels bit weird.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the dupes don't call this out. The community user owns downvotes _on posts_, but that's not the votes that _Community_ cast - it's the ones it received, which aren't tracked.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - *Though upvotes are not officially explained, most likely they belong to deleted users.* Do you mean upvotes by deleted users belongs to the Community user?

Comment: @hims056 when a user with lots of activity is deleted, sometimes the team is manually transferring the important things to Community user to preserve them, most likely this includes upvotes so that it won't cause a big rep loss for many users. This is just a guess though, so prefer a dev to confirm before including in an answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know of at least one instance on SO where that was indeed the case.

Comment: Cheers @Flexo, Kevin already gave the answer. +1 to him! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few automatic downvotes, which get attributed to the community user.

- Spam/offensive flags add a downvote
- Questions closed for certain reasons *used to* get an auto-downvote. They no longer do, but the old ones are probably counted in the totals you see.
- Very Low Quality flags that are dismissed as helpful trigger an automatic downvote.

Normally when a user is deleted, their votes are deleted as well. However, in exceptional cases, i.e. when removing all their votes would be disruptive to the community, their votes are transferred to the community user so they aren't deleted with the account. That most likely accounts for the upvotes.